# Angular5: window.addEventListener stuck browser tab

Tags: javascript, window, angular5, addeventlistener, crosstab

My app is having multiple tab support. So I am saving all the data in localStorage. The app is also having socket support and on successful login, I have to authorize socket by emitting an event.

Now in one scenario, what if the user has open multiple tabs before login and then get logged in from one of tab then all tab should work in sync.

All tabs will get token as I have stored token in local but with this, I also have to authorize my socket as all tab will be having individual socket instance.

I need some event which triggers an event to all other tabs to authorize socket instance. For that, I have used following tab listener from the reference stack codes but its stuck my browser tab.

```
window.addEventListener('storage', (event) => {
  if (event.newValue === 'socketAuth') {
    if (event.key === 'sendAuth') {
      console.log('Send Auth Event');
    } else if (event.newValue === 'disconnect') {
      console.log('Disconnect Socket');
    }
  }
});
```

It's working fine in one of my demo but not in this. Any correction that I need to do or any other way to achieve this. My app code is in Angular5.